i want to check how many vnc servers i have running on my linux system
I have checked the number of vnc servers running on my linux system using the command: ps -ef | grep vnc
i got the following output:

But i couldn't see exactly on which port is it running how to check that?

Please don't post images of text.

You found the grep process, nothing more. See How can I prevent grep from showing up in ps results?
